# Warning Implicit Declaration of posix_memalign

Tags: c, linux, gcc, posix

I am using GCC 4.9 on ubuntu 15.04.  I am coding in eclipse CDT.  This is a C program with the dialect set to c99.  For some reason my compiler keeps warning me about this...

`warning: implicit declaration of function ‘posix_memalign’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

I am not sure why.  I have `#include<stdlib.h>` at the top and when I use eclipse the ctrl+click posix_memalign it takes me to the function declaration in stdlib.h.  Why am I getting this warning?

I just tried changing the dialext to std=gnu99 and this fixed the issue.  Is posix_memalign not included with c99?

Comment: requirement: `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600`

Comment: I checked those.  My values were greater.

Comment: `stdlib.h` doesn't specify prototypes for the contained functions, (eg.  `putenv()` or `getenv()`). So if you want to get rid of the implicit function declaration warnings, add the prototypes to your source files.

Comment: @PoojaNilangekar: Perhaps because they are in `fenv.h`? Do not declare standard functions in your own source files!

Comment: This is no C standard function. So you have to include a different header.

Comment: My gnu libc6 v2.13 defines `posix_memalign` for exactly what *Sourav* mentions in his comment above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438554/warning-implicit-declaration-of-posix-memalign#comment52741258_32438554)

Comment: "You checked those. My Values were greater"  You do NOT check those.  Rather before the `#include <stdlib.h>` there needs to be a line similar to: ` #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE (200112L)`

Comment: Passing `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L` to the compiler as command line option would also do the job.

Comment: @user3629249. Thanks! I will keep this in mind next time.

Comment: @PoojaNilangekar,  Bad idea to write your own prototypes for the system functions.  Rather, read the man page for the desired functions.  The man page indicates what header files need to be included and what #define is needed to make the header file actually define those prototypes.  or place the appropriate strings in your environment via 'set' , in the .profile or similar file.

Answer (score 6):

The `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` and other [feature test macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) have to be defined before any `#include` lines.

This is because the macros tell the standard C library headers which features it should provide in addition/instead of the standard C library features; the features are "locked" at the point of `#include`.

[`posix_memalign()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html) is provided by `stdlib.h`, but only if POSIX.1-2001 or later are enabled; this means defining `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` as `200112L` or larger (the L is there because it is an integer constant of `long` type), or `_XOPEN_SOURCE` with `600` or larger.

The error shown only occurs when

1. The macros were not defined when `stdlib.h` was included

   or
2. `stdlib.h` was not included

   or
3. The C library implementation does not provide POSIX.1 features

Using GCC in Ubuntu, it has to be one of the first two, because the C library most definitely does provide these POSIX.1 features.